# Matplotlib boxplot: what algorithm is used to calculate range and identify outliers?

Tags: python, matplotlib, boxplot

I'm currently working on my masters dissertation. I've processed all my data in custom-coded Python, and one of my main methods of displaying data is the boxplot in matplotlib. I've been looking at the documentation, but I can't see anything about how it categorises outliers (or "fliers") and excludes them from the range.

It's not the end of the world if I can't find this information, but it feels incomplete to me if I don't fully describe my statistical instruments in the methodology chapter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [matplotlib.pyplot api documentation of boxplot](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot). boxplot has a `whis` parameter that specifies the range for the whiskers. With a dedault value of 1.5.

> whis : float, sequence, or string (default = 1.5)
>
> As a float, determines the reach of the whiskers to the beyond the
>   first and third quartiles. In other words, where IQR is the
>   interquartile range (Q3-Q1), the upper whisker will extend to last
>   datum less than Q3 + whis*IQR). Similarly, the lower whisker will
>   extend to the first datum greater than Q1 - whis*IQR. Beyond the
>   whiskers, data are considered outliers and are plotted as individual
>   points. Set this to an unreasonably high value to force the whiskers
>   to show the min and max values. Alternatively, set this to an
>   ascending sequence of percentile (e.g., [5, 95]) to set the whiskers
>   at specific percentiles of the data. Finally, whis can be the string
>   'range' to force the whiskers to the min and max of the data.

The default of the range of the whiskers thus is 1.5* the interquartile range. In practice that means that any value lower then Q1 - 1.5* the interquartile range and any value higher then Q3 + 1.5* the interquartile range will be considered an outlier when using the default value.

Given a non default value the output will be adjusted for that value.

Comment: So it was right in front of me the whole time, and I just kept looking past it! Thanks -- that's exactly what I needed. I think I'll just recreate all my charts with whis=range then. (Otherwise, I have to justify calling anything an outlier in a population of 6....)

Comment: Checking the documentation of anything you use if you have a question about it is always a good idea. But then again documentation can be quite daunting when you start out with programming. Glad to be of help!